# CSS / JS animation on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I'm trying to build a simple online js game (I'm taking a course at the moment and wanted to have a little experiment). I downloaded the game duck hunt (https://github.com/MattSurabian/DuckHunt-JS) and expanded it from there.

I have added levels / adjust the game fine however I have added a character on the screen by using CSS and adding it into the html (switching the game from a first person view to more a third person perspective)

[image: gamescreen]

I would like to add an animation from when you click on the screen water will come from the statues mouth and hit the enimies... at the moment there is a flash when the user clicks however i wish to change this I'm not sure how this would be achieved?

Any help would be grateful.

Flash Screen Code at the moment :

```
//bind to gun events
        this.playfield.on('gun:out_of_ammo',_.bind(function(){this.outOfAmmo();},this));
        this.playfield.on('gun:fire',_.bind(function(){
            this.flashScreen();
        },this));

flashScreen : function(){
    $(".theFlash").css("display","block");
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('.theFlash').css("display","none");
    },70);
}
```

CSS:

```
.theFlash{
    background:#ffffff;
    width:900px;
    height:500px;
    position:relative;
    margin:0 auto;  
    z-index:10;
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: Can you show us what you already have (Code)

Comment: I have added the flash code used at the moment (it just make the screen go white for a second like a 'flash') I however wish to have an water animation come from the statue at this point...

Comment: I'm tempted to let you try this yourself instead of posting a complete code example. From my perspective, what you would need is a separate element (or, if the statue can have multiple shots simultaneously, multiple elements) that is manually animated towards its target position each frame by JavaScript. (For good animation when you expect to call 60 times a second, look into `requestAnimationFrame` instead of using `setTimeout`)

Comment: Hi Katana, I have looked into requestAnimationFrame however it has seemed to confuse me even more (guess its being new to js) is there any chance you could post a solution so I can see how it works and learn from the code that way? Thank you

Comment: Still stuck on this one I seem to be making it worse?...

Comment: Any chance you can find the code that's moving those crabs (or, I would guess, ducks) around in the original code? Then, see if you can adapt that to your own moving object.

Comment: I done it! In the end I solved it by making the flash css show a gif when clicked I then simply adjusted the other divs z-index and changed for flash time (from 100 to 400) thank you for your help!

Answer (score -3):

You should look up `:hover` for css http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp

```
:hover {
    css declarations;
}
```

Comment: "*when you click on the screen water will come from the statues mouth and hit the enimies*" This one-liner answer hardly seems to come close to that goal. I don't think pure CSS is the right approach.